# load next xml element on click via ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I need to be able to cycle through an xml file using a click function. When the page loads I want only 1 xml element to load and then using a click function load the next. Kind of like content slider but loads each one when requested. I'm using it to display a you tube video with a title.

Here's my code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "video.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('video').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var embed = $(this).find('embed').text();
            $('<div class="video"></div>').html('<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+embed+' frameborder="0"></iframe><h2>'+title+'</h2>').appendTo('#video_block');
        });
    }
});
});
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<video>
<title>Title 1 here</title>
<embed>FScJfrh80UY</embed>
</video>

<video>
<title>Title 2 here</title>
<embed>FScJfrh80UY</embed>
</video>
```

Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

Here is my current code now - it needed a slight couple of tweaks because of some errors...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var i = 0;
getVid();
$('#prev').bind('click', function() {
i--;
getVid();
$('.video').remove()    
return false;

})
$('#next').bind('click', function() {
i++;
getVid();
$('.video').remove()
return false;

})
function getVid() {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
    url: "video.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        oVid = $(xml).find('video:eq('+i+')');
        var title = oVid.find('title').text();
        var embed = oVid.find('embed').text();
            $('<div class="video"></div>').html('<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+embed+'" frameborder="0"></iframe><h2>'+title+'</h2>').appendTo('#video_block');
    }
});
}
});
```

It kind of works but the following problems exist:

- It needs to show the first xml element by default - it currently shows nothing. ***I know have this working. Put getVid() before the click event functions!
- When you hit "next" for the first time it starts on the 2nd xml element.
- When you hit "next" on the last element it needs to go back to the first. Currently it tries to find a next element but comes back with nothing (as nothing exists obviously after the last!)

Many thanks again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;

$('#prev').bind('click', function() {
    i--;
    getVid();
}
$('#next').bind('click', function() {
    i++;
    getVid();
}
function getVid() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "video.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            oVid = $(xml).find('video:eq('+i+')');
            var title = oVid.find('title').text();
            var embed = oVid.find('embed').text();
            $('#videoDiv').html('<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+embed+' frameborder="0"></iframe><h2>'+title+'</h2>');
        }
    });
});
```

This code will probably not directly work but It's an idea. Play with it and you'll get it going.

**edit**

I forgot to increase i, that's why the click event didn't work!

**edit2**

If you make a button with id 'prev' and a button with id 'next' the above edited code should work.

Comment: Hey thanks. It works on one hand - where it only loads one element. The click event doesn't really work. What I need now is away of cycling forward and backward through the xml elements (with some basic controls) using a fade in and out effect.

Comment: I forgot to increase i, the click event will probably work now, try again with my edited code

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know how you would be able to use a next and previous type nav to cycle through the xml elements?

Comment: Hey thanks very much, please see my answer to the question for the current situation.

Comment: Hi, all I now need to do is disable next or prev if I am at the first or last element. 

Thanks, Matt

Comment: add if statements to the click events. so `if(i>0)i--;` to the prev button and `if(i<yournumberofvids)i++;` to the next button